# Spring 4 project not working after adding websocket handling xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-4, spring-websocket

I have a spring4 webapp which works perfectly fine , but after adding spring websocktes configuration xml my app refused to map any http get request.
Error message : Dispatcher servlet doesnt find any handler for this maping.

My web.xml looks like

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>webapplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>webapplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

My webapplication-servlet.xml looks like

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" p:order="1"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:order="2"/>
```

Till now every thing works fine as i am getting every request mapping from dispatcher servlet

but after integrating spring websockets in my app my dispatcher servlet doesnt map any http request to my any of the controllers.
I added below code snippet to my webapplication-servlet.xml and i also tried to add this in my application context also.

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/ws">
      <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic"/>
  </websocket:message-broker>
```

Comment: From your description, it seems like a case of conflicting dependencies. Check your container (Tomcat?) log output, there might be a ClassCastException in there, indicating conflict over some WebSocket-related class. You will then need to manually remove the "duplicate" JARs from your WEB-INF/lib folder (eg, Glassfish's Tyrus) or update your maven/ivy/gradle configuration file. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530654/websockets-with-tomcat-8-and-spring-4-classcastexception-before-handler-is-invok

Comment: I ran into this problem too.  Did it ever get resolved?