# websockets in tomcat7 spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, websocket

I have a spring boot war file I'm deploying to a tomcat 7.0.78 instance. The web applicaiton starts up fine, but the web sockets aren't working. They run fine in an embedded tomcat environment, e.g. running `./gradlew bootRun`.

The error I'm getting in my chrome console is:

```
angular.js:14525 Possibly unhandled rejection: Whoops! Lost connection to http://localhost:8080/websock
```

I tried setting the tomcat connector to use the Http11NioProtocol, but it seems to have no effect.

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       connectionTimeout="20000"
       redirectPort="8443" />
```

I also tried setting it as the ROOT.war, and the browse then indicates: `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/websock/424/wzkek0zw/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500.`

Is there somethign in a tomcat config file I'm missing to properly enable websockets? My web socket configuration class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfiguration  extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/websock").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

I haven't edited anything in web.xml, and have changed only the connector protocol in server.xml.

Update:
Part of my problem wsa that my connection attemps had a slash in the front, e.g.
$stomp.connect('/websock'), so I changed it to $stomp.connect('websock'). THis works fine on a windows install of tomcat, but doesn't work on an ubuntu install. I have to explicitly tell it to connect to http://localhost:8080/websock in my javascript, but then I get a follow on error trying to connect to the web socket:

```
webSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/websock/940/qdb1xkkp/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

Comment: Looking up your stack trace I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23546192/592355 ... and it sounds most likely as a version/implementation clash between `org.apache.tomcat.websocket`and `javax.websocket`

Comment: You're right. i had tried adding javax.websocket, but it caused more problems. Part of the problem was my paths were wrong when connecting, but i'm still having issues. updating answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was that I had to get the base url correct before connecitng to the socket via stomp:

```
var getUrl = window.location;
var baseUrl = getUrl .protocol + "//" + getUrl.host + "/" + getUrl.pathname.split('/')[1];
$stomp.connect(baseUrl + '/websock', {})
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer now.